# Update package.json version using command or manually

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a difference between using `npm version patch|minor|major` to update the version in `package.json` and changing it manually (change directly in the file)?

They said it's not recommended to change `package.json` manually.
Is that true?

Comment: `npm version` doesn't _just_ change the `package.json` file.

Comment: it makes update also ?

Comment: By default it also updates the lockfile and creates and tags a commit - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-version